# How to use VSCode snippets inside a JSON file's value string

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I have a `.json` file and i've created snippets under `json.json` for user snippets. Is there anyway I can get access to them inside the values' string of the JSON object. e.g:

```
{
    "someKey": "some value [INSERT SNIPPET HERE]"
}
```

i've tried:

```
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": true,
    "comments": true,
    "strings": true
}
```

with no joy, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Super old question by now but for anybody that still needs the answer:
In addition to editing `editor.quickSuggestions` like op did, you have to go to Tab Completion in Setting and turn that on (I put it on "onlySnippets").
This feature is off by default, even if you can use Snippets with tab without it being on for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Define a keyboard shortcut for `editor.action.showSnippets` (Command: `Insert Snippet`).

Inside the string hit the keyboard shortcut and type the snippet prefix.